# Add a class/function to an engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've came across a nice authorisation plugin CanCan which adds some functionality to application.

- Method 'can?' is available in views and controllers.
- And also if you create a class 'Ability' with overridden 'Initialize'
  method in models dir it is detected and some configuration is done
  basing on this 'Initialize' method.

I would like to add similar functionality to my engine. I need to know how:

1. add a function/method that will be available in views and controllers of my engine and also in the host app. Notice that I can't use ApplicationController/Helper as they don't exist in an engine.
2. create a class (probably a singleton) that would automatically be initialized at the start of application
3. I should be able to override this class'es 'Initialize' method in some user directory (like e.g. models dir)

Any help appreciated.